# jQuery does not update textArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

First of all: I'm relatively new to jQuery, so please be gentle ;)

What I'm trying to achieve: I have a Java server (backend) which does some text parsing and offers a REST-style API. On the other side (front end) I have an HTML file with a form and few lines of jQuery code.

```
<html>
<body> 
  <form id="form">
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><textarea id="input" name="input" cols="100" rows="50" type="text" placeholder="Input your code here..."></textarea></td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnTranslate" type="submit">Translate -&gt;</button>
        </td>
        <td><textarea id="output" name="output" cols="100" rows="50" type="text" placeholder=" "></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btnTranslate').click(function () {
      var valueOfTextArea = $('textarea#input').val();
      $.post("/parse", $('textarea#input').val(),
              function (data) {
                  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                  $('#output').val("" + data);
                  $('#input').val(valueOfTextArea);
              }
      );
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is: the data gets send, is translated on the server side and is send back to the client, resulting in an alert window popup, at least some times. The textAreas however are never updated properly.

I've searched Google a lot and tried almost all of the suggestions on this site. With no luck so far.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is strange. I would suggest you open up the javascript console and run the two commands with appropriate value. Is the alert working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What do you mean by saying "the textareas are never updated **properly**"?
2. Are you sure you do not receive any errors in console?
3. Make sure you are running the script on the server because your browser might block the requests
4. Try adding fallback methods. Start with something like this:

   ```
   valueToSend = $( "#input" ).val();
   var request = $.post( "/parse", valueToSend, function() {
     alert( "success" );
   })
     .done(function() {
       alert( "second success" );
     })
     .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
     })
     .always(function() {
       alert( "finished" );
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. This way I found out, that Chrome fails with an error whereas IE does not.

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help. What kind of error do you get with Chrome?

Comment: Just the alert "error", but that led me to something else I could work with. I will answer the question with the solution as soon as I am allowed to do so.

Comment: the error occurs due to his buttons are submitting to your page and then there's nowhere to ajax fired reply

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, as I learned in a loooooong debug session with one of my coworkers, is:

```
    $('#btnTranslate').click(function (event) {
        var valueOfTextArea = $('textarea#input').val();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("/parse", valueOfTextArea, function (data) {
            $('#output').val(data);
            $('#input').val(valueOfTextArea);
        });
    });
```

So you need to prevent the default click-action, as it causes a "status 0" on the XMLHttpRequest somehow. I still don't get the whole picture, but at least it works now.

Thank you all for your input.